# Can't connect to my local LDAP server : "the server is not operational"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap, openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP for Windows on my machine, but not able to connect to my local LDAP sever from my ASP.NET application.

The first step I have in my code is the creation a new DirectoryEntry instance:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://maxcrc.com");
```

It throws an exception saying "The sever is not operational"

I have tried LDAP clients programs and they seem to connect fine to localhost or (127.0.0.1) with the following DCs:

```
DC=maxcrc,DC=com
```

I tried several ways to connect but nothing including (LDAP://localhost, LDAP://DC=maxcrc,DC=com or LDAP://localhost/DC=maxcrc,DC=com)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to specify the port number when connecting via `DirectoryEntry`:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389");
```

I would, however, recommend taking a look at the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace for actually facilitating the server connection, particularly the `LdapConnection` class - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172017/how-do-i-connect-to-a-locally-installed-openldap-service) is a good starting point, and does a good job of illustrating the benefits of this approach.

Also, keep in mind that traffic going over port 389 (ldap vs. ldaps) will be in plain-text, which can be insightful when diagnosing connection issues. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is your best friend in this scenario, and has built in TCP filters specifically for LDAP communications.